# How to read data from scale through ethernet using a client program

Tags: c#, client, scale, ethernet

I have to connect Avery ZM510 scale to to a pc via ethernet. basically it should listen to the scale for data when user press print button.   the  suppliers said the scale is already configured as a server and gave an IP and said no need of a port number.

I tried below client program but no luck. Avery manuals also not containing any information about the API.

```
     using System;  
     using System.Net;  
     using System.Net.Sockets;  
     using System.Text;  
  

   public class SocketClient  
    {  
    public static int Main(String[] args)  
    {  
        StartClient();  
        return 0;  
    }  
  
  
    public static void StartClient()  
    {  
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  
  
        try  
        {  
         
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");  
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];  
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, "");  
  
          
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  
  
            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.    
            try  
            {  
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint  
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);  
  
                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
                    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  
  
                // Encode the data string into a byte array.    
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");  
  
                // Send the data through the socket.    
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);  
  
              
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);  
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",  
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));  
  
                // Release the socket.    
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
                sender.Close();  
  
            }  
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());  
            }  
            catch (SocketException se)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());  
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());  
            }  
  
        }  
        catch (Exception e)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Why are you trying to send something to localhost if your intention is to get something from a remote host? If you have no information about an API, how could you hope to accomplish anything in code?  Without knowing anything more about it, if I were told that it was already configured as a server and no port number or any API details was specified, I would interpret that to mean that I could just navigate to it using a web browser. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Plasmadog Thanks for the  reply the above code  is  nothing but a part from client server program i copied from Microsoft. . sending some thing is cps i thought necessary for to do a eco test . I have experienced in connecting  all the other ways to connect to scales . here i m really upset about Avery's lack of technical details even the scale is very expensive. . yes I tried the URL thing and it doesn't bring any API but pining is working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Scale IP and port and any simple client program will work.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        msg("Client Started");

        clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.1", 8888); // Scale Ip and port

        label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");

        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);

        serverStream.Flush();



        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];

        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

        msg(returndata);

        textBox2.Text = "";

        textBox1.Focus();
    }

    public void msg(string mesg)

    {

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Daavid. Why do you send some text from `textBox2.Text`, can you give an example of that text?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the AWTX ZM510 is sold, it is configured with a static IP to send a print string to 192.168.1.51 port 1. (unless the technical person that set it up changed these values.)

Test this socket, by opening the port in a terminal client, such as PuttY. (telnet 192.168.1.51:1) Then press the PRINT button.

Thereafter you can write your socket application in C#

--
My line of work is to provide technical support for Avery equipment - The ZM510 is a very capable device.